# MySQL Grouping by two different dimensions

Tags: mysql

If I have a tables

```
`account`, `account_contact`, `contact_event` and `event`
```

And the following FK's exists

```
`account_contact`: `account_id`,`contact_id`
`contact_event`: `contact_id`, `event_id`
```

How do I query the frequency of attendance for accounts of 'total tickets' of all contacts linked to the account and event, and distinct number of events that contacts of the account attended.

I have the following however the JOIN causes the first sub query to return duplicate `Ticket's Sold` rows with identical values.

```
SELECT a1.id,`Tickets Sold`, a2.`Distinct Events Attended` FROM

(SELECT a.id, count(*) `Tickets Sold`
 FROM account a JOIN account_contact ac
     ON ac.active = 1 AND a.id=ac.account_id
 JOIN contact_event ce
     ON ac.contact_id=ce.contact_id
 JOIN event e
     ON ce.event_id=e.id AND ce.role = 'Checked In'
 WHERE e.date_start >= '2015-12-31' AND e.date_end < '2017-01-01' 
 GROUP BY a.id ) a1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT a.id,count(*) `Distinct Events Attended`
 FROM account a
 JOIN account_contact ac
     ON a.id=ac.account_id AND ac.active = 1
 JOIN contact_event ce
     ON ac.contact_id=ce.contact_id AND ce.role = 'Checked In'
 JOIN event e
     ON ce.event_id=e.id
 WHERE e.date_start >= '2015-12-31' AND e.date_end < '2017-01-01'    
 GROUP BY ac.id ) a2

ON a1.id=a2.id
```

Example Output showing the problem: As you can see Distinct Events is returning the number of tickets sold to the company for that particular event, so in the example there were 8 events attended,

```
AccountId   Tickets  DistinctEvents
38110518    15       5
38110518    15       1
38110518    15       3
38110518    15       2 
38110518    15       1
38110518    15       1
38110518    15       1
38110518    15       1
```

Instead I should return:

```
AccountID   Tickets    DistinctEvents
38110518    15         8
```

**EDIT**: Example Data

```
SELECT id,name FROM account;
id  name
100 Big Company


SELECT id,first_name FROM contact;
id  first_name
200 John
800 Other


SELECT contact_id,event_id FROM contact_event;
contact_id  event_id
200 300
200 500
800 300


SELECT account_id,contact_id FROM account_contact;
account_id  contact_id
100 200
100 800


SELECT id,name FROM event;
id   name
300  Big Event
500  Small Event
```

Should return:

```
AccountID   Tickets    DistinctEvents
100         3          2
```

Comment: Please post sample input data and expected output based on it in the question

Comment: Just change the second to last line to group by a.id instead of ac.id.  See my answer.

Comment: I'll post some data in a few minutes. Just making some up.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.

Comment: @gurV have added input data + expected output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    a.account_id,
    count(event_id) tickets,
    count(distinct event_id) distinct_events
from account_contact a
inner join contact_event e
on a.contact_id = e.contact_id
group by a.account_id;
```

Comment: Can't believe it's so simple - I need to learn more about distinct modifier and grouping. Thanks so much